# Grey border of the button element in Chrome, OS X

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am trying to style the `button` element. On Chrome, OS X it still leaves a grey reflection-style border around the element no matter what, though.

I *do* have `-webkit-appearance` as well as `outline`, `border` and even `box-shadow` all set to `none` so it's none of them

Here's a screenshot of the element and the strange border: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDw4L.jpg

Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of it?

CSS:

```
button { /* a part of http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#addNew {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #33f;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 15pt;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="addNew">+</button>
```

**UPDATE:** The button also seems to still have Chrome's default blue focus hue despite setting `-webkit-appearance` to `none` so it's probably some special `-webkit` property that I'm not aware of.

Comment: can you please post your source code or css?

Comment: @Jainam Updated the question with source code.

Comment: Please check my answer and fiddle link may be you need this .

Comment: It's working on chrome.

Comment: The blue focus hue is the outline property on the :focus state I think